# How to make 2 JavaScript function's execution mutually exclusive?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two select elements with several options, I chain them together so that each updates automatically when the other one changes.

```
// ########### Linked Labour Select Boxes
$('body').on('change', '#labourList > li .labourerID', function() {
    var id = $(this).val();
    $(this).parent().find('.labourerName').val(id).change();
});


$('body').on('change', '#labourList > li .labourerName', function() {
    var id = $(this).val();
    $(this).parent().find('.labourerID').val(id).change();
});
```

At the moment one method will trigger the other one making my page a bit slow, how can i avoid that?

Comment: Can you post a jsFiddle?

Comment: verify the `new value` and `old value` . If they both are same then do not invoke `change`. Otherwise invoke `change`. You need to verify this in both events.  I think the problem you are facing is each event is invoking other event continuously. That's going `infinite`.  Checking condition before firing `change` is the best thing i could think of for now.

Comment: Why are you explicitly firing `change()` event?

Comment: Instead of `.change()`, use [`.triggerHandler("change")`](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/). Read the docs to find out why. [Here's a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pnd3132s/1/)

Comment: Oh didn't know it was bad to do that @squint , i can't anything against it in the docs do you know where i can find something? Thanks

Comment: @Heraclitus: It's not bad, but there are benefits in your case to using `.triggerHandler`, specifically because it doesn't trigger the native event, so you don't end up with the recursion issue you're experiencing. So `.change()` is good for triggering an actual event, but it seems more like you just want to run the function.

Comment: Oh I see @squint ! That makes sense, thanks for the info, I will use this when I want to trigger the element's method specifically that uses change().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used a flag to communicate that the change that occurred on the select is because of user of the script.

Check this.

When the user changes one select nothing is executed in second select so the change chain is broken.

```js
var script_triggred_change = false;

$("#one").change(function() {
  console.log("Called One");
  if (script_triggred_change) return;
  script_triggred_change = true;
  $("#two").val($("#one").val()).change();
  script_triggred_change = false;
});

$("#two").change(function() {
  console.log("Called Two");
  if (script_triggred_change) return;
  script_triggred_change = true;
  $("#one").val($("#two").val()).change();
  script_triggred_change = false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="one">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select id="two">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: How could I not think of this, what's wrong with me, programming 101.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```js
var once = false;
$('select').on('change', function(e) {
  if(once) { 
    once = false;
    return;
  }
  
  once = true;
  $('select').not(this).val($(this).val()).change();   
});
```

```css
select, option {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
   <select class="lab-ids">
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <option value="4">4</option>
     <option value="5">5</option>
   </select>

   <select class="lab-name">
     <option value="1">Peter</option>
     <option value="2">Hans</option>
     <option value="3">Fritz</option>
     <option value="4">Sandra</option>
     <option value="5">Jessy</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're doing here, I think you're calling a specific elements change function when any of the two change. Is that right? It certainly looks elegant and quite smart. I've fixed my problem by using good old flags.